# HQL custom order ASC and DESC

Tags: sql-order-by, hql

I have the following situation:

I have a bill with a year (e.g. 2000, 2001, ...), a boolean that says whether the bill was paid or not and different other values like a persons name.

It comes that I want to display them in a list in a specific order. The oldest unpaid bill should be on top and the oldest paid bill should be at the bottom. Also it should be sorted by the name.
Like:

```
Name   Year  PAID
Smith  2010  false
Otto   2018  false
Anon   2018  true
Hueue  2018  true
Otto   2017  true
Smith  2009  true
```

Something like that...

```
"from Bill as b order by b.paid, b.year, b.name"
```

This clause sorts the list like:

```
Name   Year  PAID
Smith  2010  false
Otto   2018  false
Smith  2009  true
Otto   2017  true
Anon   2018  true
Hueue  2018  true
```

I tried to achieve my goal with HQL (order by case...) but I don't know how to order the same row in different ways depending on a value.
Like: (this does not work)

```
" from Bill as b" +
" order by" +
" b.paid," +
" (case b.year" +
"   WHEN b.paid" +
"   THEN b.year" +
"   ELSE -b.year" +
" end)," +
" b.name"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Edit: Added more explanation and examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
from Bill as b
order by
    b.paid,
    case when b.paid = 'false' then b.year else -b.year end,
    b.name
```

This works by first placing unpaid bill records before paid records.  For this first sort condition we need not use a case expression because `false` sorts before `true`.  For the year order, we do need a case expression.  Here we sort ascending by year for unpaid bills and descending for paid bills.

Comment: Are you sure? My result says something else. Please have a look at the new information I provided.

Comment: That works exactly as I needed. Thank you very much!